# Date and time stamp comparison with today in ODBC in Excel?

Tags: sql, excel, t-sql, odbc

### Question

I'm querying a DataBase via Excel ODBC.

**I can compare the field with an hard-coded date** in my **Excel's ODBC query** with :

```
BOMD.BOMENDDAT_0 > {ts '2018-05-05 00:00:00'}
```

But **I can't seem to make a proper comparison with the present date** :

```
BOMD.BOMENDDAT_0 > {ts SYSDATETIME()}
DATEDIFF(d, SYSDATETIME(), BOMD.BOMENDDAT_0) > 0
```

**Any suggestion ?**

---

### Context

I'm trying to build a query that select only records where the date of today is between :

- a start date (`BOMD.BOMSTRDAT_0`)
- an end date (`BOMD.BOMENDDAT_0`)

Those dates :

- are in a special format, they look like this in Excel : `'26/02/2018  00:00:00'` 
  (French format, *Day Month Year*)
- can be filled or not
- 0 seems to be `'00/01/1900  00:00:00'`

The whole query look like this :

```
SELECT BOMD.BOMQTY_0, BOMD.UPDDAT_0, BOMD.BOMSTRDAT_0, BOMD.BOMENDDAT_0
FROM myDB.BOMD BOMD
WHERE BOMD.UPDDAT_0 > {ts '2018-01-01 00:00:00'}
AND (
    (BOMD.BOMSTRDAT_0 < {ts SYSDATETIME()})
    OR BOMD.BOMSTRDAT_0 = 0
    OR BOMD.BOMSTRDAT_0 is null
    )
AND (
    (BOMD.BOMENDDAT_0 > {ts SYSDATETIME()})
    OR BOMD.BOMENDDAT_0 = 0
    OR BOMD.BOMENDDAT_0 is null
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{ts '2018-05-05 00:00:00'}` is used to convert string into datetime data type, you cannot use it on `SYSDATETIME()` which is already a datetime (precisely datetime2) data type, just make it:

```
SELECT BOMD.BOMQTY_0, BOMD.UPDDAT_0, BOMD.BOMSTRDAT_0, BOMD.BOMENDDAT_0
FROM myDB.BOMD BOMD
WHERE BOMD.UPDDAT_0 > {ts '2018-01-01 00:00:00'}
AND (
    (BOMD.BOMSTRDAT_0 < SYSDATETIME())
    OR BOMD.BOMSTRDAT_0 = 0
    OR BOMD.BOMSTRDAT_0 is null
    )
AND (
    (BOMD.BOMENDDAT_0 > SYSDATETIME())
    OR BOMD.BOMENDDAT_0 = 0
    OR BOMD.BOMENDDAT_0 is null
    )
```

btw, your code will also return rows where both `BOMENDDAT_0` and `BOMSTRDAT` are zeros or nulls, is it **really** intended behaviour?

Comment: Sorry for the late accept, your answer finally helped me to make this work ! I forced the date-"0" to be displayed in text and added `BOMD.BOMSTRDAT_0 = {ts '1753-01-01 00:00:00'}`. And yes I ain't responsible for the "management" rules so it's indeed the intended behavior ;) Many many thanks !